# Qt Custom Widget Fail to Find Object Files

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt-designer

I have a group of custom widgets that I am integrating into Qt designer and when I attempt to build it, it throws `LNK2005`, `LNK2019`, and a `LNK1120`. It seeems to be focusing around my `QtMaterialFabPlugin` file so I will provide the example code based upon that. It also basically says that every function of `QtMaterialFabPlugin` is already defined in the corresponding `.obj` file. Here is my relevant code, and any help on this is greatly appreciated.

QtMaterialFabPlugin.h:

```
#ifndef QTMATERIALFABPLUGIN_H
#define QTMATERIALFABPLUGIN_H

#include <QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface>

class QtMaterialFabPlugin : public QObject, public QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface)


public:
    QtMaterialFabPlugin(QObject *parent = 0);

    bool isContainer() const;
    bool isInitialized() const;
    QIcon icon() const;
    QString domXml() const;
    QString group() const;
    QString includeFile() const;
    QString name() const;
    QString toolTip() const;
    QString whatsThis() const;
    QWidget *createWidget(QWidget *parent);
    void initialize(QDesignerFormEditorInterface *core);

private:
    bool m_initialized;
};

#endif
```

QtMaterialFabPlugin.cpp:

```
#include "qtmaterialfab.h"
#include "qtmaterialfabplugin.h"

#include <QtPlugin>

QtMaterialFabPlugin::QtMaterialFabPlugin(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent) {
  m_initialized = false;
}

void QtMaterialFabPlugin::initialize(QDesignerFormEditorInterface*) {
  if (m_initialized) return;
  m_initialized = true;
}

bool QtMaterialFabPlugin::isInitialized() const { return m_initialized; }

QWidget* QtMaterialFabPlugin::createWidget(QWidget* parent) {
  return new QtMaterialFab(parent);
}

QString QtMaterialFabPlugin::name() const {
  return QLatin1String("QtMaterialFab");
}

QString QtMaterialFabPlugin::group() const {
  return QLatin1String("Material Widgets");
}

QIcon QtMaterialFabPlugin::icon() const { return QIcon(); }

QString QtMaterialFabPlugin::toolTip() const { return QLatin1String(""); }

QString QtMaterialFabPlugin::whatsThis() const { return QLatin1String(""); }

bool QtMaterialFabPlugin::isContainer() const { return false; }

QString QtMaterialFabPlugin::domXml() const {
  return QLatin1String(
      "<widget class=\"QtMaterialFab\" name=\"qtMaterialFab\">\n<widget>\n");
}

QString QtMaterialFabPlugin::includeFile() const {
  return QLatin1String("qtmaterialfab.h");
}
```

Material-Widgets.pro:

```
CONFIG      += plugin debug_and_release
TARGET      = $$qtLibraryTarget(qtmaterialwidgetsplugin)
TEMPLATE    =

HEADERS     = qtmaterialappbarplugin.h qtmaterialautocompleteplugin.h qtmaterialavatarplugin.h qtmaterialbadgeplugin.h qtmaterialcheckboxplugin.h qtmaterialcircularprogressplugin.h qtmaterialdialogplugin.h qtmaterialdrawerplugin.h qtmaterialfabplugin.h qtmaterialflatbuttonplugin.h qtmaterialiconbuttonplugin.h qtmateriallistplugin.h qtmateriallistitemplugin.h qtmaterialmenuplugin.h qtmaterialprogressplugin.h qtmaterialradiobuttonplugin.h qtmaterialraisedbuttonplugin.h qtmaterialscrollbarplugin.h qtmaterialsliderplugin.h qtmaterialsnackbarplugin.h qtmaterialtableplugin.h qtmaterialtabsplugin.h qtmaterialtextfieldplugin.h qtmaterialtoggleplugin.h qtmaterialwidgets.h
SOURCES     = qtmaterialsliderplugin.cpp qtmaterialappbarplugin.cpp qtmaterialautocompleteplugin.cpp qtmaterialavatarplugin.cpp qtmaterialbadgeplugin.cpp qtmaterialcheckboxplugin.cpp qtmaterialcircularprogressplugin.cpp qtmaterialdialogplugin.cpp qtmaterialdrawerplugin.cpp qtmaterialfabplugin.cpp qtmaterialflatbuttonplugin.cpp qtmaterialiconbuttonplugin.cpp qtmateriallistplugin.cpp qtmateriallistitemplugin.cpp qtmaterialmenuplugin.cpp qtmaterialprogressplugin.cpp qtmaterialradiobuttonplugin.cpp qtmaterialraisedbuttonplugin.cpp qtmaterialscrollbarplugin.cpp qtmaterialsnackbarplugin.cpp qtmaterialtableplugin.cpp qtmaterialtabsplugin.cpp qtmaterialtextfieldplugin.cpp qtmaterialtoggleplugin.cpp qtmaterialwidgets.cpp
RESOURCES   = icons.qrc
LIBS        += -L. 

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
    QT += designer
} else {
    CONFIG += designer
}

target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/designer
INSTALLS    += target

include(qtmaterialextrafiles.pri)
include(qtmaterialraisedbutton.pri)
include(qtmateriallist.pri)
include(qtmaterialradiobutton.pri)
include(qtmaterialslider.pri)
include(qtmaterialtextfield.pri)
include(qtmaterialtoggle.pri)
include(qtmaterialdialog.pri)
include(qtmaterialtable.pri)
include(qtmaterialautocomplete.pri)
include(qtmaterialbadge.pri)
include(qtmaterialcheckbox.pri)
include(qtmaterialavatar.pri)
include(qtmaterialcircularprogress.pri)
include(qtmaterialappbar.pri)
include(qtmaterialfab.pri)
include(qtmaterialdrawer.pri)
include(qtmaterialsnackbar.pri)
include(qtmaterialmenu.pri)
include(qtmateriallistitem.pri)
include(qtmaterialflatbutton.pri)
include(qtmaterialtabs.pri)
include(qtmaterialiconbutton.pri)
include(qtmaterialscrollbar.pri)
include(qtmaterialprogress.pri)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, I just had to add the

```
TEMPLATE    = lib
```

to the `.pro` file.